# Show authors latest comments on author.php

Tags: mysql, wordpress, comments

I have a Wordpress site and I've set up an `author.php` page where a users information is displayed.

Currently I've managed to get it to show the authors latest posts they've add to the site using `query_posts`.

However, I want this page to also show the authors latest comments he has posted on the site, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with a query, as I'm not sure if Wordpress supports this feature.

Comment: post the schema of your tables.

Comment: Can you elaborate pls JW?

Comment: the comments were save on the database right? I want you to post the important tables so we can help you build the query..

Answer (score 0):

There's a function for this: [**`get_comments`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

Example usage (based on the Codex example):

```
$auth_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
$defaults = array(
    'author_email' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'karma' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => '',
    'orderby' => '',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'parent' => '',
    'post_ID' => '',
    'post_id' => 0,
    'post_author' => '',
    'post_name' => '',
    'post_parent' => '',
    'post_status' => '',
    'post_type' => '',
    'status' => '',
    'type' => '',
    'user_id' => $auth_id,
    'search' => '',
    'count' => false,
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'meta_query' => '',
);
$auth_comments = get_comments( $defaults );
var_dump( $auth_comments );
```

***Important note:*** avoid using `query_posts`, see: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Comment: Thanks Brasofilo, that's certainly pointed me in the right direction. What if I wanted to show comments from the current author if he has posted comments and show a default a message like: This user hasn't posted any comments yet - if he hadn't. Using an if else statement, what would the full code be?